# Can I edit multiple animation transitions at once in the Unity Editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible to edit a group of animation transitions at once?  When I select several animation transitions (as in the screenshot below) and change some properties in the Inspector (such as Transition Duration), the changes don't seem to take effect.  The properties look like they change, but when I click elsewhere in the Editor and then click back on the transition, the property still has its old value.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Multi-editing for animation transitions isn't supported.

Source: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/transition-editing-multiple-transitions-cannot-be-edited

Comment: Well that's a bummer.  Thanks for the link.